# What is the package name for "Task Manager" in Android to launch this activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to launch Task Manager using Intent from my application. What is the package name for the Task Manager? I.e.,

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.<task_manager_package_name>"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this snippet to get package name of task manager

```
   apps=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA|PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS|PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS); // gets all app details on phone

String packagename = new String(); 

  for(int index=0;index<apps.size();index++)
    {
        PackageInfo temp = apps.get(index);     //Iterate through the apps till you get task manager
        if(temp.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString().equals("Task Manager")))
        {

          packagename = temp.packageName; //To get package name
          break;
        }

    }
```

Then the string packagename will have the packagename of task manager

Comment: Sorry for the heavy editing.. I had to modify my code to present it here.. hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActivityManager, read more about that. [Check this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)

Comment: Perhaps provide an example?

Comment: I think he can search examples himself.

Comment: Got the answer its "com.sec.android.app.controlpanel"  Thanks

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i=manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.controlpanel");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
//Works Perfectly

Comment: @SagarDate actually it doesn't work this way anymore, and since it's not a real official way, this can crash.