# how to open the task Manager on a button click in android?

Tags: android, taskmanager, recent-file-list

I want to open the Task Manager (recent apps window) by clicking a `Button` in android. When I will be clicking that `Button`, I need the task manager window (which normally arrives by long pressing the home button or clicking the recent apps button) to be available. But can't find anything on Web that is really helpful. Please help me guys. Desperately need the answer. I am completely out of idea about this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please tag you question with library / major technology involved (android in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to open the Recent Task list via a Button - it is not accecible.

However, you could quite easily create your own using `getRecentTasks`

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29) for more information.

Good luck!

Comment: But I have seen some apps doing that. GetRecentTasks actually gives the list. But I don't want the list. I want to popup the task manager window whenever I will click the button. It will work as it is. Is it possible @gilonm??? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the Task Manager (and not the Recent Task List) - Read [here])http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563470/what-is-the-package-name-for-task-manager-in-android-to-launch-this-activity) for what you want

Comment: Many many thanks @gilonm. At least this gives me a clear outline.

Comment: This method worked for me-private void toggleRecents() {
     Intent closeRecents = new Intent("com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS");
     closeRecents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
     ComponentName recents = new ComponentName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity");
     closeRecents.setComponent(recents);
     this.startActivity(closeRecents);
 }